# How to pass SDL_Surface to SDL_LockTexture with PySDL2?

Tags: python, sdl-2, pysdl2

I'm trying to pass SDL_Surface members to SDL_LockTexture:

```
texture = SDL_CreateTexture(renderer, SDL_PIXELFORMAT_ARGB8888, SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_STREAMING, width, height)
surface = SDL_CreateRGBSurface(0, width, height, 32, 0x00FF0000, 0x0000FF00, 0x000000FF, 0xFF000000)
SDL_LockTexture(texture, 0, ctypes.byref(surface.contents.pixels), ctypes.byref(surface.contents.pitch))

TypeError: byref() argument must be a ctypes instance, not 'int'
```

SDL_Surface is defined here: [surface.py](https://bitbucket.org/marcusva/py-sdl2/src/971c36e3dbd7ee8f0b9b25873345e30509376cd8/sdl2/surface.py?at=default)

```
...
class SDL_Surface(Structure):
_fields_ = [
            ...
            ("pitch", c_int),
            ("pixels", c_void_p),
            ...
...
```

SDL_LockTexture is defined here: [render.py](https://bitbucket.org/marcusva/py-sdl2/src/971c36e3dbd7ee8f0b9b25873345e30509376cd8/sdl2/render.py?at=default)

```
SDL_LockTexture = _bind("SDL_LockTexture", [POINTER(SDL_Texture), POINTER(SDL_Rect), POINTER(c_void_p), POINTER(c_int)], c_int)
```

After calling SDL_CreateRGBSurface the debugger says that both the pixels and pitch members of the surface are of type int. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having the same problem, trying to pass the pixels into `PyOpenGL` functions. For some reason the field is stored as an `int`. You need to cast it to a `void pointer`. Try:

```
SDL_LockTexture(texture, 0, ctypes.byref(ctypes.c_void_p(surface.contents.pixels)), ctypes.byref(ctypes.c_int(surface.contents.pitch))
```